# Limit of $\cos(1/x^2)$ as $x$ tends to $0$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\cos\frac{1}{x^2}$

I understand that through the squeeze theorem we know the upper bound is $1$ and lower bound is $-1$

I understand that it would be undefined at $0$ and that there would be an infinite number of oscillations as $x$ tends to zero, but then what after this?

I cannot seem to crack this one.

Comment: Well squeeze theorem does not tell about upper and lower bounds, rather we use upper and lower bounds to apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let consider

$$x_n=\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

and take the limit $\cos (1/x_n^2)$ for $n$ odd and for $n$ even.

Comment: @AnuragA Opsss yes of course! Thanks I fix that

Comment: this shows the continuous oscillations from -1 to 1, not sure how to apply this ...

Comment: @fred two subsequences converging to two different limits, so the limit......??

Comment: @fred Recall that if the limit exists, by definition, any subsequence must have the same limit, therefore if we find at least two subsequences with different limit the limit can't exist.

Comment: limit from 0^+ and 0^- are different hence there is no limit.

Comment: @fred No the point is different here, just take $x_n=\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ and evaluate the limit for n even and n odd, what do you obtain?

Comment: @fred Your idea is correct but you need to make it rigorous and for that we need to exhibit two subsequences with different limits. That's the standard way to proceed to prove that a limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @fred You need to clarify the definition of limit. From that it easy to prove that when liit exists it is unique and in that case if $f(x)\to L$ as $x \to a$ then $f(x_n)\to L$ for any $x_n\to a$. Is that point clear to you?

Comment: yes. Thank you!

Comment: Then in that case we have that for $x_n=\frac1{\sqrt{2n\pi }}\to 0 \implies \cos(1/x_n^2) \to 1$ while  for $x_n=\frac1{\sqrt{(2n+1)\pi }} \to 0 \implies \cos(1/x_n^2) \to -1$